# Background Image is not being responsive

Tags: html, css

During responsive web designing I noticed that whenever I reduce the width lower than 1140px (row width) the background image(header & review), background-color (footer)and image(meal photo section) get reduced to a smaller size and doesn't cover the 100% width of the browser.

Please and check the code let me know the issue in my code.

I have attached the issue image link at the end.

Link:

Github: https://github.com/toth2000/Web-Page

[Issue Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkXsH.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are on-topic, however, you need to post the relevant code you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an overflow where you have fixed width 1140px for the `.row`. Also, an overflow happens on the twitter link. Besides that, another overflow will happen for the h2 for smaller screen size. With these 3 changes on `.row`, `h2` and `.twitter-link`, it will work well for screen seize above 245px.

**style.css**

```
.row {
    width: 100%; /* Change from 1140px to 100% */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.twitter-link {
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e98310;
    transition: border 0.2s;
    word-break: break-word; /* Add word-break */
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 350;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    word-break: break-word; /* Add word-break */
}
```

The remaining overflow for screen size below 245px is the `img.app-photo`, we can force the width from auto to 100% with a media query.

**style.css**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 245px) {
  .app-photo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It fixed the issue.

Comment: @TothagataBhattacharjee Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it wouldn't be 100%.
Because you are making parents divs smaller than your childs.
When childs get bigger then parent can't controll them any more.
If you are using bootstrap use container and cols to make em in a nice position and responsive.
I will make one of your sections responsive then you can understand what's the problem.
The funniest point is you have the problem only on inspect.!